# spring boot postgresql 9.5.3 dependency

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-boot

**Update:**

As suggested in the answer below, use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1211</version>
</dependency>
```

Check this link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/9.4.1211

and this one:
https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc

---

It is possible to use the postgresql version 9.5.3 in a maven spring boot project?
In that case, what I have to write in my pom.xml? Since I can't find code like this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

for the version I want to use, and if I write 9.5.3 inside the version tag maven can't find the right jar for the project.

Comment: And it's not in the driver download page, I forgot to mention: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: Choose one from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql, seems the driver for 9.5 is not in maven repository yet, so you can just choose the latest one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the *driver* is not and doesn't need to be the same as the version of the *server*. If you use the [newest driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.4.1211.jar) as is recommended, it will work just fine with Postgres 9.5.3.

As a dependency the version should be `9.4-1211-jdbc42`.

Comment: Thank you, for other possible users that want to know it:

Comment: `  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1202-jdbc42</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Oh, is 1202 the latest version in the repository? I didn't check.